# Added new redirected domain with lots of visitors bouncing - is that bad for us?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, multiple-domains, bounce-rate

We're a very niche domain marketplace, which has a few hundred domain names for sale, and most all of them are redirected to our site. Most get a few clicks a day, as they are non-keyword (generic terms)

We've just gotten a big domain name on board, and it's gotten about 1000 visitors for the day -- MORE THAN our actual site traffic gets without it -- most of all which are bounces. We plan to also have more names like this soon, whereas we'll receive tons of redirect traffic.

Is this bouncing traffic going to negatively affect our ranking or our SEO?

Or is the added number of visitors of greater weight than the increased bounce rate?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15607/a-bounce-rate-attack-to-manipulate-seo?rq=1

Comment: This question is in relationship to adding a redirected domain with high bounce rate, versus a "bounce-rate attack", and includes additional factors such as having multiple redirected domains.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of speculation after Google's updates as to if [bounce rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_rate) is now an SEO metric, signal, etc...and how it might be measured in terms of these (see [this](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/marketing/bounce-rate/) for one such discussion).

Regardless, most would likely agree that a high bounce rate is not going to help your SEO, and the goal should be to try to engage visitors to stay on your site, versus building traffic from visitors that just leave.

Another important thing to consider is that redirecting hundreds of domain names to your site might not be wise as Google's Panda update was meant to target sites which appear to be [domain farms](http://searchengineland.com/google-forecloses-on-content-farms-with-farmer-algorithm-update-66071). So planning on adding more domain names with high bounce rates might just trigger penalties from that, which would certainly negatively affect your site's ranking.