# Will copying and pasting a link from the search results contribute to click through rate?

Tags: search-results, ranking, ctr, competitors

If I copy and paste a link to a new tab from the search results, will Google count this action towards the click through rate which could influence the ranking?

If many people click a link in a search result, the link could get better rankings. If I see a competitor's link in the results, I would not click it but copy and paste its URL to the address bar. I'd like to know whether or not this would prevent search engines from counting my click and possibly helping my competitor.

Comment: See also: [Is click through rate from the search results an important ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71497/is-click-through-rate-from-the-search-results-an-important-ranking-factor-for-go)  It isn't a sure thing that Google uses clicks in the search results to influence rankings.  Google has actually denied that clicks influence rankings.

Comment: How are you copying the link?  Are you right clicking and copying the link URL, or are you selecting the text of the URL from below the page title from the results?

Comment: Do they make any difference? I sometimes right-click, sometimes select the text. I don't think Google can detect that.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: I think it could matter which way you do it.  One way might avoid tracking redirects.