# Does Google penalize if I click on my own website in the organic search results?

Tags: seo, penalty, ctr, clicks

I want my website to go up in SEO.  I have been giving it about 40c licks every day. Do you know if Google penalizes for that?

Comment: You are just wasting your time.  Click through rate may not be a ranking factor at all, and if it is one, it isn't a strong one: [Is click through rate from the search results an important ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71497/is-click-through-rate-from-the-search-results-an-important-ranking-factor-for-go)

Comment: I never heard that someone got penalized clicking his / her own link. I am wondering why someone would do this anyway? Do you want to improve CTR? CTR is only one of numerous ranking factors. I doubt you will see positive results. It is a waste of time...

Answer (score 3):

Just because someone clicks on a link, doesn't mean Google thinks it's a good link.  There are hundreds of other factors.

First, Google is fully aware of the hundreds of games website owners use to try to boost their rankings.  I'm sure Google has even accounted for scripting programs that will visit your website from multiple IP addresses and navigate to your site.  And equally aware of negative SEO attacks using similar methodology (though in my experience, their algorithm isn't perfect at detecting these).

**Questions we believe Google's algorithm is asking**

But here are some other questions Google's algorithm is probably using when a user clicks on your site.

Does the user stay for any length of time on the site, or do they immediately click back (implying the page didn't answer the user's query)?

Does the user visit other pages within the site (Implying that the user at least found some of the content interesting)?

Does the user go back to Google and click on other pages with the SERPs (Implying that the previous pages didn't answer the user's question)?

Does the user go back to Google and ask the query again, but in a different way  (Implying that the pages visited answered a different question than what the user was looking for)?

**Does clicking on my own site boost or hurt my rankings?**

Lastly, Google knows your IP address, unless you're using a VPN (and they probably recognize it's a VPN).  They know your IP address from your logging into gMail, Google Search Console, Analytics.  As such, multiple visits a day, especially from the same IP, probably just looks like the owner is visiting their site, and most likely is ignored.

**A better way to improve your Google ranking**

Personally, I would spend my time developing good content, that answers users' questions instead of trying to play games with search engines.

Instead, spend time reading some of the great input to questions people ask over and over again here.  You can find these at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: I already have good content, but how are users supposed to visit my page if it is on page 7 in google results?

Comment: @dostoyevski, give it time.  Ranking in the SERPs takes months to achieve.