# Is thin content taking into account only the number of words?

Tags: seo, thin-content, word-count

I am interested to know whether a page is treated as a thin content page based on only the fact that there are a few words.

What if the page has around 100 words but together with that it has a useful tool that has nothing to do with word count and there is no need to write anything more?

Will that page still be treated as thin content?

I could not find a proper answer anywhere to this question.

Comment: For more info on thin content, take a [look at this video from Google’s former head of web spam, Matt Cutts.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3-obcXkyA4) It’s not a particularly recent video but everything Matt Cutts says is still relevant today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have free tools available on my website that have minimal words on the pages as they are pretty self explanatory.  However, the tools relate to the overall website.  About 50% of the web hits to the free tools come directly from search engines, and the rest from internal links.  So, i don't think you need a lot of words to explain your page.

FYI, Google doesn't use word count to determine the quality of a page.  What search engines do is match your content to the user's query.  Where long form content helps, is it provides more content for the search engine to understand from your semantics what you are trying to say.

Since you don't have a lot of content, search engines will use lots of other techniques to see if the content actually matches what the user requests.  Take a look at [Does Google penalize if I click on my own website in the organic search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131309/does-google-penalize-if-i-click-on-my-own-website-in-the-organic-search-results/131315#131315) for what Google may try to use to evaluate your thin pages.