# Does referral spam really have a negative impact on my SEO?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, referrer

In Google Analytics, more than half of my traffic is from referral spam. This has a dramatic impact on my bounce rate -- which many sources claim is strongly tied to search ranking by Google.

I can negate a small amount of this by blocking the requests that *actually* visit my site -- but these are the minority. A lot (~80%) of the undesired traffic simply sends the necessary JavaScript call to Google to fool their systems.

So my question is: **should I care?** Does it *actually* matter outside of messing up my view on Google Analytics (that can be trivially dealt with via filters)?

Comment: I am curious. Are any of your referrer spam these?? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-referrer-spammers/75914#75914 If so, here is a bit of background that may be interesting.

Comment: @closetnoc yes! actually, I think I did read that question before asking my own. that list in your answer contains the undesirables. thank you.

Comment: These folks you cannot block. They are hacking Google directly. I have pinged someone at G about these twice. But I suspect it would take some time to move the meter within a large company so I do not expect much movement on these. I do know that for some of these, the spam has seemed to stop, though the stats are still in the data. I hope that G is paying attention.

Comment: @closetnoc yeh -- I realised I couldn't block them (since they're not actually getting to my server). my question was really just about whether I should care about it them affecting me in some other way. :)

Comment: I do not think so. Google really does not take GA stats and use it for their search engine metrics. This is more of an annoyance. I am not sure what the pay-off would be for this. Normal referral spam makes some sense given two factors: one, it creates back links in web stats automatically posted for some sites; and two, it makes you curious who these people are and might visit just to see. I assume that the second factor would be a pay-off spamming Google directly. Still, this does nothing for a particular site- really. So I really do not see the point in doing this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not. Your [Google Analytics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLmO1GE4GvI&feature=player_embedded#at=14) is not a ranking factor. So garbage referrals, or anything else in your analytics, will not affect your ranking.

Comment: Thank you! So is all that about Google basing search position on bounce rate bunk then?

Comment: There are other ways to determine bounce rate. I don't think bounce rate is anything to note but others disagree.

Comment: Thanks again. I can't seem to upvote your answer, but thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: See [this answer I wrote about Google relying on bounce rate](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/does-a-sites-bounce-rate-influence-google-rankings/54336#54336)