# Will fast duration visit user with happy experience can lower my page ranking?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, ranking

Hello I'm currently running page wish has regular traffic, this page has made only for linking or referring to other websites, The users can find what they looking for in my page, but the user bounce rate, of course, is too low because as I said it refers to other websites/articles

Will that reduces my page ranking on google?

Or Google can count it as good behavior and upper my page.

waiting for your experience

Comment: Can you share the bounce rate? Lowest bounce rate is good sign to get ranked, it tells Google that user is engaging with your page and it can be preferred to saw on relevant user queries. For more I would like to know some statistic like No. of sessions, number of users, bounce rate, exit rate, session duration to tell you exactly.

Comment: That is a worst bounce rate, keep it below 60%, make you content engaging and interactive, otherwise this will kill your current rankings and Google will keep piggybacking your pages and your rankings will fall gradually. Thanks to the Rank Brain.

Comment: Hi, My Bounce rate is 88% pages session 1.2 Avg session duration 00:52.
As you said could google count it as the user engaging with my page.
the page contains links to different websites. so the reason for the page is to refer to other websites on the web. and the visitor has really no interest to do in my page then go where they were looking for
the links I pointing too is set to be opened in a new tab when someone clicks. rel="nofollow noopener

Comment: "nofollow" will tell crawlers to not visit those urls and "noopener" will create a separate instance of process instead using the one which created the new tab.

Comment: What type of resources you've on your website, I would like to check them, can you share your website's URL?

Comment: See also: [Does a site's bounce rate influence Google rankings?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/does-a-sites-bounce-rate-influence-google-rankings)

Comment: @DeepakMathur I would like to share my website but I can't. for my web page is hard to keep the visitors for more than 1.60 seconds, anyway thanks for the info.