# Bad robots kill my SEO with high bounce rate on certain pages

Tags: seo, analytics, bounce-rate

They open a page and then leave immediately. What's the best practice to fight it? Time 1-2 s, bounce rate = 100%

I googled several services, for example this one shows this IPs like spam, but they are fighting spam comments, not total IP blocking.
https://cleantalk.org/blacklists/as29209

[image]

Comment: Search engines don't see bounces unless the user clicks through from search results and then clicks the back button to return to search results. Any reason to believe these bots are affecting your SEO?

Comment: I have reason: which keywords they use - that ones go down in search engines. I'm sure they use some software.

Comment: Are you specifically seeing visitors bounce from SERPs to your website then directly back to the same SERP? Those are the only type of bounces that search engines can see.

Comment: I see this 100% bounce rate in analytics, and I can see when it has grown grammatically from 7% to 70% when competitors started this kind of attack. They started with best keywords, after they go out of top 30 they took next one, than next one etc

Comment: Apologies if this is my inexperience showing, but I see no reason to believe that these are SERP -> website -> SERP bounces. Even if they are, they [should not affect SEO](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-does-not-use-pogo-sticking-as-a-ranking-factor/261629/). From my understanding of your question, it is impossible for bots to affect your SEO in any way whatsoever through bounce rate.

Comment: Sorry may be I call it 'bots' and this is completely wrong and gives wrong result in our discussion. I mean - special software which goal is to simulate behaviour of a "real" people, real devices don't like the exact website. They stamp is like this: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 YaBrowser/19.3.3.161.10 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; Lenovo A5000 Build/LRX21M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.86 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: It's correct to call them bots, I just don't understand how bounce rate could be affecting your search engine ranking at all. Maybe someone else will drop by and shed some more light on this.

Comment: See [Does a site's bounce rate influence Google rankings?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13920/does-a-sites-bounce-rate-influence-google-rankings)