# Ahrefs Orphan Page Error - SEO Friendly Pagination using JavaScript

Tags: canonical-url, url-parameters, pagination, clean-urls, technical-seo

One of my clients is a Cybersecurity startup company. We are using a custom built theme on Drupal. We have a well-designed internal link building architecture.

We have about 600 blog articles. We are listing them on category listing pages. Here, a user can sort and filter these articles. He can also see 9, 18 or 27 results per page.

We are maintaining the pagination using Vanila JavaScript. Here, **to provide a better user experience, we are not showing any parameterized URL during pagination.**

That means, if a user is on the first page or second page, he sees the same URL. For example

- Page 1: https://www.example.com/blog/cybersecurity/
- Page 2: https://www.example.com/blog/cybersecurity/
- Page 3: https://www.example.com/blog/cybersecurity/

and so on...

Now, I am getting Orphan Page Error in Ahrefs. The I have been told that all these 600 blog articles are actually Orphan Pages because they are not linked from the parent page.

So is there anything else supposed to do for the coding wise?

- I also referred to this [SEJ article](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/technical-seo/pagination/)
- I also referred to this article on [Pro WebMasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137516/are-orphan-pages-on-a-job-board-an-seo-problem)

We can definitely change the coding, and show a parameterized URL for pagination, although, it will not lead to a better UX. So what should we do in this case?

Is there any other method we can use here?

Comment: I recommend [removing pagination and finding other ways to link to all your pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/123637). The SEJ article you linked has good advice if your pagination is the only way to navigate to your pages, however that shouldn't be the case if you want good SEO for pages that aren't on the first page of the category.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but by the time, I went through a lot of changes in the website. Although, the Orphan page errors are still remaining. I am still in process to figure out what else could be done. Changing the entire code on listing page would not help, as it impact the entire website performance. The good thing is, these pages are available through Sitemap, so atleast they are crawlable and indexable.

Comment: Our developer team said, they are using vanilla javascript to pull content from the database server. So I am not sure if I need to re-write the entire listing page code logic just to solve this Orphan page issues.

Comment: Ahrefs bot doesn't execute JavaScript but Googlebot does.  This may be a case of that tool being inadequate.  Googlebot will execute the JavaScript, find the links and know the pages are not orphans.  Ahrefs won't parse the JavaScript and give you false warnings.

Comment: okay great. Yeah, this make sense. I also checked through another tools and errors are not appearing.